# C# Updating multiple text boxes with similar names

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple textbox names such as R1TotalCost, R2TotalCost, R3TotalCost, all the way up to R25TotalCost. Is there anyway to edit the text values, and or text colours to them all using a code simular to this

```
for (i=1; i <=25, i++) {
    string TextBoxName  ="R" + i + "TotalCost";
    TextBoxName.text = "£25";
    TextBoxName.Foreground = Brushes.Green;  
}
```

Comment: Use MVVM. This is madness. You need to write a little class th store a TotalCost and maybe a string for a name, then have a collection of those that you put together with a loop. Bind that to an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate. Let WPF do all the hard work. Many examples can be found on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this since you seem to want to update them all at once, would be to create an `Array` or `List` that contains all of the `TextBox` elements. Then your can go through them all like below!

```
        foreach (TextBox tb in myTextBoxes) {
            tb.Content = "UPDATED CONTENT!";
        }
```